# Path to Images not Working in Angular 2

Tags: html, css, image, angular

Everything I have put on my site functions correctly, but every image that I try to put into the site (with the exception of the background) gives back a `404 Not Found Error`.

All of my images are located at "Project/src/assets/images" and I have tried the following img tags in my html documents. The documents are located in "Project/src/app/tabs".

```
<img src="src/assets/images/image_name.jpg"> 
<img src="/src/assets/images/image_name.jpg">
<img src="./src/assets/images/image_name.jpg">
```

I set the background image for my page using css and it works. This is the selector and the attribute I have applied:

```
background: url('assets/images/greybackground.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

How can I add images to my HTML documents without getting the 404 error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your html files are in **"Project/src/app/tabs"** and you are trying to access from that folder thats why images are not loading.
So you need to come back from **tabs** folder and **app** folder to reach the base directory for both your code and images.
Use `../` to come back from a folder. So after reaching base directory just use normal directory listings.

So answer is

```
<img src="../../assets/images/image_name.jpg">
<img src="../../assets/images/image_name.jpg">
<img src="../../assets/images/image_name.jpg">
```