# Can't serve images in angular 2 applications

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm try to display one image saved in the `assets/img` folder.

I did this :
`<img src="../../../assets/img/login_fb.png" />`

Considering the fact the image is called in a template located in `app/auth/signin/mytemplate.html`

in my angular-clir.json file, i have the following lines:

```
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "../public/",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
```

Thank you in advance for your help

---

**Update** 05/04

I tried to display this image in a brand new angular project and it works correctly. Obviously there is something causing the issue in my existing project.
**Note that when i try to access the image directly by url, i'm redirected to the home page of my angular application**

I have an angular guard but it's not used on the route i'm trying to display the image ( the image is inside the signin template )

```
export const APP_ROUTING: Route[] = [
    { path: '', component: HomepageComponent },
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
    { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent },
    { path: 'profile', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: ProfileComponent }


];
```

Server side there is also this line in my app.js but i don't think it can cause the problem isn't it ?

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});
```

**Update 2 : My full app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const index = require('./routes/index');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


mongoose.connect('mongodb://arn:blabla@ds227459.mlab.com:XXXXX/databasename', {
    keepAlive: true,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE
  }, function (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Connexion opened to mongodb!');
    }
});

//t
app.use(index);

app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true }));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: inspect the src in browser and open in new tab and check again ..

Comment: in the browser , the src contains ../../../assets/img/login_fb.png

Comment: i think ../../../ not required in src url

Comment: Thats not is told here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336991/path-to-images-not-working-in-angular-2

I did the same thing as this guy but it's not working. Can't believe i can't just display an image...lol

Comment: open image in browser check url path and try that as src, ..

Comment: @Slrg that answer may be outdated. Given that it was in February of 2017, there's a fair chance that the OP was not using the Angular CLI. Try using paths relative to the root, instead. For example: `<img src="assets/img/login_fb.png" />`.

Comment: not working too :( , still getting a 404 error in the console

Comment: Can you provide the full server side code? Or, at least all the routes that before `app.get('*', ...);`?

Comment: I just updated my question adding the full app.js code. In the other routes there is nothing that can cause this problem, i checked

Comment: tell me the folder structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found what was causing my problem. It was hard to find but the angular project was in a folder whose name contained "[]" characters. That seemed to be the problem. I don't know why though....?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already tried this but this works for me:

```
<img src="../assets/img/login_fb.png">
```

Comment: can't work for me since there is more than a directory between my template and my image

Comment: I understand. I have my template in src/app/nav/signin/nav.html and <img src="../assets/img/Logo.png"> is able to find the image for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ./assets/ it will definitely works.

```html
<img src="./assets/img/login_fb.png">
```